# What steps happen when reconnecting to Identity 2 Session with existing cookie

Tags: cookies, asp.net-identity, asp.net-mvc-5

What authorization steps happen when a user starts a new session and there is an existing cookie?  For example: I am logged into my application and an exception is thrown. I start a new session without closing the browser and I am not forced to login. What is happening in the authorization process to allow this to happen?
Thanks!

Asp.Net 4.5.2, Identity 2, MVC5

Comment: Identity does not use session, so it does not care about what you do with a session - you can start a new one whenever you want/need.

Comment: Thanks. I think my question isn't worded the best. I'm trying to understand what in the authorization process allows this behavior. What method(s) are called to recognize the user is already authenticated and does not need to log in.

Comment: You need to check `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`. `User` object is available in controllers or view files.

Comment: or access it via `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`